# Converting Excel to XML

Tags: xml, excel

I have hierchical data stored in a spreadsheet that I am converting into an xml using a Groovy script.

```
Col A   Col B

A         A1
A         A2
A         A2
B         B1
B         B1
B         B2
```

This needs to be as follows in XML format:

```
<A>
 <A1></A1>
 <A2></A2>
</A>
<B>
 <B1></B1>
 <B2></B2>
</B>
```

I have managed to do read it off the xls and write it to xml.I am having trouble associating A1 and A2 with a single element A My output currently looks like

```
<A>
 <A1></A1>
</A>
<A>
 <A2></A2>
</A>
<B>
 <B1></B1>
</B>
<B>
 <B2></B2>
```

What is a good programmatic way to read the excel?

Comment: you could use VBA or any other scripting language (like python) for such tasks

Comment: I am already using Groovy for the scripting..was just wondering about a good way to transform the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be fairly simple using a hash in groovy